# Data warehouses and atomicity rarely coexist

Tags: etl, data-warehouse

This came up in the context of a [humorous Tweet](https://twitter.com/BrentO/status/1433138838050836482) about wrapping a data warehouse overnight load in a transaction and how this would bloat the log file and eat up disk space. I'm not trying to disprove it but rather to understand it better - as to me it seems to imply that a partial load (due to error) should be allowed to complete which would mean that the DW would not accurately reflect the source system(s).

The only way that I can understand it is if the incomplete records would be loaded into an intermediate staging layer in the DW but not be processed further until completed by a subsequent overnight load and only then would be processed further.

I tried to research it further but without success so would be really grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

When an error happens during the loading of a DW you could:

- stop the load and rollback (either to the start of the load of a single target object, of a group of objects or the whole DW)
- Stop the load and leave the DW as it is at that point
- log the error and continue the load (either of the failing target or of other objects in the DW)

Which option you choose is entirely dependent on your particular circumstances and you might have many different strategies in use at different points in your etl pipeline and depending on the number of errors. For example:

- The error may allow you to continue to load other dims/facts without affecting them
- Your business might prefer a fact table to be loaded minus one erroring record rather than missing a complete day’s data until the error is fixed

Comment: Thanks Nick - breaking it down like that has helped my understanding, as has the point that a partial load may be better than not loading anything.